# Template Body to posts

Tags: posts

Is there any possiblity to add in a body template to the default wordpress posts? so whenever I create a post it should appear as a template inside of the body text field

Answer (score 0):

Simply add following code to your theme functions.php

```
function better_default_post_content( $content ){
    if( empty( $content ) )
        $content = "Default Template is here!";
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_editor_content', 'better_default_post_content' );
```

With "the_editor_content" filter you can filter WordPress TinyCME editor value for changing values. In this code i added a filter for that.

It's so simple if you know WordPress action filters. you can read this for action filters: http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-use-wordpress-hooks/

Comment: Please [edit] and add some details how your code is working and how it's providing the solution. :)